# GPG output missing when running unattended

Tags: powershell, gnupg

I'm trying to encrypt files through a scheduled task calling gpg2.exe within powershell 2.0

The script/task runs fine when I'm logged in, either through the ISE or by running the task in the windows task scheduler. I'm on Windows Server 2008 and the service account being used is not admin, but has access to all source and destination folders.

When the task runs unattended, the output from gpg doesn't show up in the target directory and there are no errors returned. I've added the user to the security policy to allow it to login as a batch. It is able to write files which currently exist (the source) to the target folder, just not the output from GPG.

The odd thing is that the behaviour is inconsistent, if I log in and out as that system account, sometimes the job will run unattended successfully until the schedule expires and then start erroring on the next schedule.

I'm fairly certain it's a setting around the session since it works all the time when i'm logged in and only in certain scenarios when not. any help would be appreciated.

please see the following example of how i am invoking GPG in powershell (yes, I am a noob :) )

$GPG_Prog='C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG\gpg2.exe'

$GPG_Encrypt='-e'

$GPG_Encrypt_to='-r XXXXXXXX'

&"$GPG_Prog" -o C:\location\$File.gpg --batch --quiet --yes "$GPG_Encrypt" "$GPG_Encrypt_to" \source location\$File

Move-Item \$File.gpg \network output location

thanks

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar issue with decryption and found out, that the real problem was, that the key is per default stored in the roaming Profile of the User.
So in our situation it had nothing to do with DEP and it nothing to do with insufficient rights, as the User had already "Batch execution" rights.

So we had to move the Key files from the roaming Profile to a local Directory.

Basicly these steps are necessary:
1) Find out where your key directory actually is (--list command)
2) Copy/Paste files from Roaming directory to your path (f.i. c:\winutil\library)
3) delete the "old" key
4) create new Key with --homeDir option

Please find instruction on gpg sites or here:
http://www.glump.net/howto/cryptography/practical-introduction-to-gnu-privacy-guard-in-windows#6.1_Preparing_a_Minimal_Copy_of_GPG

Start your Powershell script unattended and verify :-).
HTH,
Robert

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so while I was waiting for a response, I kept plugging away at the problem. Based on some inferences from other issues posted and researching the completely non-useful error code returned from GPG, I thought it might be DEP within Windows causing the problem.

To test it, I added the gpg executable to the exception list for DEP (not the recommended MS solution) and then scheduled all the encryption tasks to run unattended. They proceeded to kick off and run flawlessly for over an hour test period.

Based on what I have read and experienced, it seems that since GPG is running as unattended, it doesn't get the memory allocated that it would if it were running as an actual user profile logged in. Once it starts encrypting any file of a reasonable size and tries to access memory beyond the set limit marked as available for execution by windows, DEP immediately crashes the GPG instance leading to the error message in the app log that wasn't really helpful.

Anyway, hope this helps someone out there!

cheers